# Running a ping and speed test from Africa, specifically countries with no large data centers?

Tags: performance, page-speed

I have a task to run network latency and speed tests from different parts of Africa.
Specifically, I would like to run a ping test for different URLs different times of the day from those parts.

These countries rely typically on servers in other countries with large data centers.

I've thought of a few options:

- Pay a contractor from a country like Upwork or Fivrr
- Buy a VPS and run it myself
- Run from a VPN (it looks like the only servers are in South Africa, and that's not entirely helpful)
- Call an ISP and have them run it for me

Are there any better ideas or ways I could achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't run a ping or speedtest from those locations unless you have resources there.  You can run tests to/through them if you use a VPN or similar but thats not the same thing.   What countries are you looking at specifically?

Comment: Also, what are your specific goals?   Maybe we can tease out useful data in other ways - like ping tests, looking at BGP and connectivity and other meta-information.   Oh yes, and, of-course, Starlink would change the picture greatly.    Also, latency should be relatively predictable if we can establish the routes.

Comment: Have you seen https://www.speedtest.net/performance ?  It might help tease out some meaningful data depending on what you are looking for.

Comment: In https://www.webpagetest.org/ go to advance settings. Under server location, they have a test server in Africa that you can use.